# How to print out the main function arguments on the command line in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to debug this code and I can't seem to find the error that is giving me this on the command line:

```
./thisa
thisa
isa
a
test
```

Instead, it needs to give me this:

```
./arguments
this
is
a
test
```

Assuming I enter "./arguments this is a test" as my input.

Any suggestions on where the bug might be?

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void printArguments( int rows, int cols, char args[][ cols ] )
{
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      printf("%s\n", args[i]);
   }
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   // Figure out the length of the longest command-line argument.
   int longest = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
      int len = sizeof(argv[i])/sizeof(argv[0]);              
      if (len > longest) {
         longest = len;
      }
   }

   char (*words)[ longest + 1 ];
   int n = argc;
   words = (char (*)[longest + 1])malloc(n * (longest + 1) * sizeof(char));

   // Copy each command-line argument to a row of this new array.
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      strcpy(words[i], argv[i]);
   }

   // Call a function that's expecting the command-line arguments as a 2D array
   printArguments( argc, longest + 1, words );

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `argv[i]` is a pointer; `argv[0]` is a pointer. Dividing their `sizeof` always yields `1`

Comment: So would it be like this? int len = sizeof(*argv[i])/sizeof(*argv[0]);

Comment: try `strlen(argv[i])`

Comment: malloc like that doesn't give you a 2D array

Comment: your program destruct the memory writing (and also reading) out of the resources

Comment: @pmg Thanks, it worked! So when you divide sizeof on a pointer, it will always return one?

Comment: Also note that argv[0] is always the name of the program, not the first argument.  Your loop in `printArguments` should start at one instead of zero.

Comment: You get `1` when you divide equal values: `42/42`, `a/a` (when `a!=0`), `sizeof argv[1]/sizeof argv[1]`. All members of an array (argv[0], argv[1], ...) have the same type, and therefore the same size.

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a lot going on here.  If you're simply trying to print the command-line arguments, you already have your answer in the guts of your helper function.  Just use that code directly on `argc`/`argv`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
   printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
}
```

Since you go to all the trouble of copying everything out into an array with a completely different format, I'm assuming that there's more to this question than what you've given us so I'll address the question/code as written.

As several others have mentioned, the line `len = sizeof(argv[i])/sizeof(argv[0])` will always return 1 since `argv[x]` is a pointer.  To measure the length of argument number `x`, all you need is `sizeof(argv[x])`.

The line `char (*words)[ longest + 1 ]` [declares a pointer to an array](https://cdecl.org/?q=char%20%28*words%29%5B4%5D) of `(longest+1)` characters.  You then allocate a much larger buffer (`(longest+1) * argc` bytes) and assign it to the pointer.  It's not clear what you're trying to do here.  Generally speaking, when allocating a character buffer, you'd do something like this:

```
char* my_ptr;
my_ptr = malloc(num_bytes);
```

You don't need to encode anything about the size of a 1-D buffer in the pointer, a normal character pointer is all you need.  You also don't need to typecast the return value of `malloc()`.  It returns a `void*`, which will implicitly convert to any other pointer type without a cast.

The next piece of code is likely where you're encountering a lot of your problems.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    strcpy(words[i], argv[i]);
}
```

Here, `words` is a pointer to a 1-dimensional array.  This code starts by copying argument #0 to byte 0 of the destination (OK).  The next time through the loop, it copies argument #1 to byte 1 of the destination.  This is going to overwrite part of your first argument.  You have room in this buffer to write all of the arguments without overlapping, but your pointer is only a 1-D pointer (you're treating it like a 2-D pointer).  To treat the destination like a 2-D matrix, you'll need to do some of the pointer arithmetic yourself:

```
strcpy(words[i * (longest + 1)], argv[i]);
```

That will write the first argument at byte 0, the second at byte `(longest+1)`, the third at byte `2*(longest+1)`, etc., ensuring that they won't overlap.  You'll need to make a similar change to your helper function as well.